# How to pass promise result to module.exports

Tags: node.js, promise

Somebody knows how to update module.exports from outside.

I have such module, that required by another tool `Nightwatch` (takes js config). I'm stuck with promises, don't know how to solve this. Because when module loaded `start_process` is undefined.

```
// local.js
module.exports = {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: "4444",
    start_process: undefined,
    server_path: "./node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar",
    cli_args: {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver",
        "driver.version": "2.24"
    }
};

require('tcp-port-used').check(4444).then((inUse) => {
    module.exports.start_process = !inUse;
    return module.exports;
});

// nightwatch.conf.js
var server = require("./local.js");
console.log(server.start_process);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the module was just loaded, the value *is* still `undefined`. You'll either have to find a way to call `tcp-port-used` synchronously (which is usually despised but somewhat acceptable at startup), or you just export the promise itself:

```
module.exports = require('tcp-port-used').check(4444).then(inUse => {
    return {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: "4444",
        start_process: !inUse,
        server_path: "./node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar",
        cli_args: {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver",
            "driver.version": "2.24"
        }
    };
});
```

Whoever wants to use the properties from your module will have to wait for them to become available.

Comment: I already think about exporting promise, it sounds good, but module to which I pass promise doesn't work with promises. Do you have idea how it can be `require('tcp-port-used').check(4444)` properly synced?

Answer (score -2):

when you do

```
module.exports.start_process = !inUse;
```

you are actually modifying the exports of the caller's module, not the one which has the start_process variable. Try this:

```
var foreignmodule = require('tcp-port-used');
foreignmodule.check(4444).then((inUse) => {
    foreignmodule.start_process = !inUse;
    return module.exports;
});
```

Comment: I don't need to inject it to foreign module.